# Linux CLI, using var into echo with pipes

Tags: linux, command-line-interface

I'm trying to use the result of a pipe into a "var" and then use it on a echo like this way:

```sh
ls  -al --time-style=+%D |
grep `date +%D` |
wc -l |
HERE I DON'T KNOW HOW TO ASSING THE VALUE OF THE PREVIOUS PIPE INTO var |
echo "the number is %var"
```

The idea is to print "`the number is 3`" (because `ls -al --time-style=+%D |` date +%D `| wc -l` is 3)

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

One way, using command substitution:

```
$ var=$(ls -al --time-style=+%D | grep `date +%D` | wc -l)
$ echo "the number is $var"
the number is 3
$
```